# How to create a list of data sources in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I have some secrets on AWS Secrets Manager. I already created a list of all the secrets' ARN, which looks like this

```
secretList  = {
      "secret1"  = "ARN1",
      "secret2"  = "ARN2"
}
```

I can retrieve the content of one single secret using Data source, for example

```
//Get the secret ID
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
    arn = "ARN1"
}
//Retrive the latest content
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "current" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id
}
```

Now I want to create a list of all my secrets' content, how can I do that?
Since every secret can have multiple pairs of key/value, I'm thinking the results should look like this:

```
secretValue  = {
      "secret1"  = {"key1" = "value1","key2" = "value2"},
      "secret2"  = {"key1" = "value1","key2" = "value2","key3" = "value3"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each):

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
    for_each = var.secretList
    arn      = each.value
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "current" {
  for_each  = var.secretList
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets[each.key].id
}
```

Then you can access the secrets using, for example:

```
data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.current["secret1"].secret_string
```

Comment: I just tried and ran into this error: The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set. Perhaps this means I need an external script to achieve what I want here.

Comment: @HienThaiLe My code is correct. If it does not work for you it means that your question is not representative of your actual code and problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made some mistakes while adapting your code to mine. It works now.